# NHibernate, accessing data from a stored procedure that has multiple result sets

Tags: sql, nhibernate, stored-procedures, select

I have working code that looks something like this:

```
var query = CreateSqlQuery("exec spMyStoredProcedure");
query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(MyMappedObjectDTO)));
return query.List<MyMappedObjectDTO>();
```

With my stored procedure looking something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM @myTable1
```

This works fine. However, I want to (in my stored procedure) add another data set by putting in an additional select statement so that my SP would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM @myTable1
SELECT * FROM @myTable2
```

However, when I run my code, it only returns the data from the first select statement. How can I access both data sets with the resulting ISQLQuery??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. NHibernate will use only the first result set.